# What am I doing wrong when loading the DevExpress Grid Assembly on Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, devexpress, portable-class-library

I'm creating a PCL project with Xamarin Studio Community Edition and added the DevExpress Grid component to my Android and iOS projects using the Component Manager.

Then I added the DevExpress.Mobile.Grid.v15.2.dll and DevExpress.Mobile.Core.v15.2.dll assembly references to the PCL project.

After that I built the app and debugged it on the iOS simulator.

Then I added the line

```
DevExpress.Mobile.Forms.Init();
```

to the AppDelegate like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{           
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    DevExpress.Mobile.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App ());
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

and all I got was this

> Could not load type DevExpress.Mobile.DataGrid.Internal.GradientBoxView, DevExpress.Mobile.Grid.v15.2, Version=15.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null while decoding custom attribute

Then I tried adding it in the Main.cs file like in the HelloGrid example provided by DevExpress:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
    // you can specify it here.
    DevExpress.Mobile.Forms.Init();                          
    UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
}
```

But then I got this other error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Mobile.Core.v15.2, Version=15.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

I'm kind of lost here since everything is up to date and the implementation is pretty straightforward. I'm very used to my Windows-Visual Studio environment and this may be somehow related with Mac permissions on files or smth (perhaps?)

Comment: are you using the same versions of the binaries in each project?  You might want to try uninstalling the components and just add direct references to the appropriate dlls from each project.

Comment: Any updates on this?